# In what context can I say "I could come here because of you"?

Tags: context

If I made it to a special place because of someone and I'm grateful for that, which one makes more sense?

1. I could come here because of you
2. I came here because of you

Another expression-related question - which one is correct?

1. Many thanks to your generosity, I finally made it!
2. Many thanks to you, I finally made it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for your first question, neither of the options is quite perfect; your first version, *I could come here because of you,* is correct (and conveys your message) but uncommon, and the second one, *I came here because of you,* is again correct but has a different meaning- it's implication is that you are here *for* them, rather than *because* of them, if that distinction makes sense.

But, I have to say that you don't often come across that construction (at least in English), so you may want to go with one of the following:

- I'm (only) here because of your help/guidance
- I wouldn't be here with your help/guidance
- I couldn't have made it here without your help/guidance

As for your second question, once again, neither of the options is absolutely perfect (the 'many' is not necessary and it makes the sentence clunky, if not ungrammatical). They need a bit of tweaking; you could perhaps go with:

- Thanks to your generosity, I'**ve** finally made it!
- Thanks to you, I'**ve** finally made it!

---

Additionally, consider the following:

*I've finally made it thanks to your generosity!*

^Implies that you've made it as a result of their generosity

*I've finally made it; thanks for your generosity*

^This tweak (adding a semicolon/comma, changing 'to' to 'for'), changes the exact meaning of your statement, although the sentiment remains the same. You're now saying that you've made it to your destination, after all this time, and then you're thanking them for their generosity.

Basically, the difference is that, in the first one, you're saying that their generosity is what's gotten you here, and in the second one, you're saying that you've gotten there and that you are grateful for their generosity.

Congratulations on whatever you've accomplished that has merited this speech!